# Merge multiple lists of dicts, add the values of duplicates and sort

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 lists of dictionaries that I want to merge and sort. If there's more than one dict with same `_id`, the duplicate should be removed but the values of `count_enabled` and `count_disabled` should be added(sum) to the remaining one. The lists might or might not have duplicates and are of different lengths

```
Foo = [
   {'_id': 'core.system', 'count_enabled': 9, 'count_disabled': 0},
   {'_id': 'core.system', 'count_enabled': 0, 'count_disabled': 0}, 
   {'_id': 'core.private_channel', 'count_enabled': 4, 'count_disabled': 0}]
Bar = [
   {'_id': 'core.admin', 'count_enabled': 9, 'count_disabled': 0},
   {'_id': 'core.colors', 'count_enabled': 0, 'count_disabled': 0},
   {'_id': 'core.system', 'count_enabled': 0, 'count_disabled': 0}]
Baz = [
  {'_id': 'core.system', 'count_enabled': 0, 'count_disabled': 0},
  {'_id': 'core.whois', 'count_enabled': 9, 'count_disabled': 0}]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
data = []
for i in [Foo,Bar,Baz]:
    for j in i:
        data.append({'module':j['_id'], 'count_enabled' : j['count_enabled'], 'count_disabled': j['count_disabled']})

sort = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('module'))
```

I am also renaming `_id` to `module` but that is not very important, `data` is sorted correctly the only thing left is to remove the duplicates and add their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting aside, I think merging all dictionaries into a final list can be done with the code below.

I basically created a `final_list` for unique dictionary entries.

For each `dict` of your `list`s, I traverse dictionary entries (`final_dict`) in `final_list`. If I find a `final_dict` with current `_id`, I sum up the values, and break out of inner for loop to proceed to next `dict` in `list`.

If I can't find the `_id` in any of the `final_dict`s, I append that dictionary to final list.

```
final_list = []
lists = [Foo, Bar, Baz]
for lst in lists:
   for dct in lst:
      id_to_lookup = dct['_id']
      found_duplicate_flag = 0
      for final_dict in final_list:
         if final_dict['_id'] == id_to_lookup:
            found_duplicate_flag = 1
            final_dict['count_enabled'] += dct['count_enabled']
            final_dict['count_disabled'] += dct['count_disabled']
            break
      if found_duplicate_flag == 0:
         final_list.append(dct)
```

Comment: Seems to be doing what  I need except a use before defining error on found_duplicate_flag.

Comment: @Trax oh well, right. Moving `found_duplicate_flag` out of the for loop should fix it. I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on what you hope eventually to produce here.  But I'm going to assume it's a sorted list of dicts, where each dict has exactly three keys.  I'm assuming you have your reasons, but this is a very awkward structure.  Why not key on `_id` / `module`?

Something like:

```
enabled = dict()
disabled = dict()
for i in (Foo, Bar, Baz):
    enabled[i[module]] = enabled.get(i[module], 0) + i['count_enabled']
    disabled[i[module]] = disabled.get(i[module], 0) + i['count_disabled']

results = [{'module': m, 'count_enabled': enabled[m], 'count_disabled': disabled[m]} for m in sorted(enabled.keys())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can utilize Python's collections, notably `defaultdict`, and `reduce()` to merge the dictionaries.

```
import collections
import functools

# Group the dictionaries by '_id'.
records = collections.defaultdict(list)
for record in [*Foo, *Bar, *Baz]:
    id = record['_id']
    record.pop('_id', None)
    records[id].append(record)

# Combine the dictionaries from each group.
data = []
for key, value in records.items():
    data.append({ **{'_id': key, },
        **dict(functools.reduce(
            lambda x, y: x.update(y),
            [collections.Counter(x) for x in value]
        ))}
    )

print(data)
```

It is important to note that running the code above would result in the removal of any keys that have non-zero values. If you want to keep keys with non-zero values, you could replace the last `for` loop with the following code.

```
data = []
for key, value in records.items():
    combined_values = collections.Counter()
    for d in value:
        combined_values.update(d)        

    data.append({ **{'_id': key, }, **combined_values )}
)
```